# Regular expression escape warning

Tags: ruby, regex

For code

```
url.gsub(/"|\[|]| /, '')
```

ruby raises warning

```
warning: regular expression has ']' without escape: /"|\[|]| /
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex would be reduced to,

```
url.gsub(/[ "\[\]]/, '')
```